# Flutter - How to change color of marker based on magnitude of an int?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create markers at each GPS point with a color on a scale from white to red that corresponds to how slow or fast the GPS data indicates the speed is at that point. However, since `Color.fromRGBO()` [requires](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhqoC.png) `const` arguments, I'm having trouble getting the speed to change the color. How could I circumvent the Color class or find a better way to draw such a gradient than with Marker objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/Color.fromARGB.html

```dart
const Color.fromARGB(
    int a,
    int r,
    int g,
    int b
)
```

with `a=0`, `g=0` and `b=0` and use your scale (you need to know the maximum value, lets call it `r_max`, to normalize the range). So whenever you have an intensity value, lets call it `r_intensity`, you'd simply compute

```dart
const r = 255 * (r_intensity / r_max)
```

to compute your color intensity. The result of `r_intensity / r_max` will always be in range [0, 1] multiplied by 255 to conform with

> r is red, from 0 to 255.
> from the docs.

Regarding the const issue: it sounds like you want to (heavily?) animate the color. Look at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html and set the red color value to your Widgets state.

Other than that, it should work to either have

1. a method that returns the new red value (and does the aforementioned computation)
2. simply use `var r = ...` instead of `const r = ...` and pass it to Color

---

Looking at your image, the issue might stem from your int being null. Please make sure that your Color Widget is not wrapped into any Widget prefixed with `const`! This will likely be the case here and produces the result you are seeing. Tested it on my side to confirm.